# How to make login API in node.js using mysql database

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, api, node-mysql

i am new in node.js and i want to make a login api using express and mysql database,Please share with me your idea and example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you should familiarise yourself with the express framework.

Secondly you'll want to create a mysql database with the following tables:

1. Users

   - userId | name | other fields...
2. Authentication_tokens

   - userId | token

These will be the building blocks for your application. Basically from here you'll be able to authenticate http requests with a single `token`, this `token` will be assigned to a `userId`.

Once we have the database setup we can start to add in the `express` routes.

1. Add in an authentication route

The below route will mean that **`all`** requests that have the `/api/v1/` prefix in front of them will go through the `./api/middlewares/validateRequest` file before continuing.

```
app.all('/api/v1/*', [require('./app/middlewares/validateRequest')]); // Authenticate all api/v1/ req
```

The validateRequest file could look something like this:

```
module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
  // When performing a cross domain request, you will recieve
  // a preflighted request first. This is to check if our the app
  // is safe. 
  // We skip the token outh for [OPTIONS] requests.
  //if(req.method == 'OPTIONS') next();

    // CHECK FOR A token inside the header of the request
    var token = (req.body && req.body.access_token) || (req.query && req.query.access_token) || req.headers['x-access-token'];
    var key = (req.body && req.body.x_key) || (req.query && req.query.x_key) || req.headers['x-key'];
    ... DO ALL YOUR MYSQL QUERIES HERE TO VALIDATE THE TOKEN
```

2. Add in your other routes below...

If you want a route to be authenticated, then add in the `api/v1/` prefix.

```
app.use('/api/v1/post/', require('./app/services/post/index.js'));
```

This is a very basic example. I suggest you look at some tutorials! E.g

1. https://codeforgeek.com/2015/01/nodejs-mysql-tutorial/
2. http://teknosains.com/i/simple-crud-nodejs-mysql

If you don't want to build the mysql database and queries yourself, you could look into using an `ORM` such as sequelize: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize

Comment: No worries! Practice makes perfect (: @aldy

Answer (score 0):

Use [Express](http://expressjs.com/) framework to create an API in node.js. Please go through it. It is simple and faster way for developing API. Use the following libraries to parse your request

https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser

```
app.route('post',function(req,res,next){
   console.log(req.body);//here you will get all the API body 
   // use req.body.emailkey and req.body.passwordkey to find the user in mysql
})
```

Plase go throuh the express library first. I hope you can create any kind of API by using express.